# How do social media sites get a preview of a linked page?

Tags: javascript, c#, facebook

I don't know how to start on this problem. When you paste a URL into a Facebook, Twitter, etc comment or post, the system will go and generate a preview of the page you linked. If I can get a conceptual model, it should be possible for me to translate that into Javascript or C# by myself.

Comment: I think you should look at https://moz.com/learn/seo/meta-description

Comment: If you mean the preview image certain websites show, check this out: https://www.addtoany.com/ext/meta-tags/. If you're looking to make an actual screenshot of the page, you will have to download the page (serverside) and render an image from the retrieved HTML.

Comment: I am not web developer, but I am sure there is no magic: you have to know about every url to be able to render something. E.g. if it's youtube, you use their api, then you can get link to video and embed player on your page (the user can watch videos without visiting youtube, but not all videos). You will have to add support for each such *playable/displayable* content manually (e.g. for facebook you can get profile photo using their api). Of course you can *try* to use meta description for unknown sites for some small description, but that's just small text.

Comment: Have a look at -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer  or  for more browsers and code support -> https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

Comment: Why are edgelords voting to close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've tagged this post with Facebook. If you are concerned with Link Previews as they appear when shared to Facebook, here is some relevant information for you. There is something called Open Graph tags that web developers can put on their pages. These are scraped/retrieved by various services that provide previews. For example, see Facebook's [Sharing Debugger Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) along with an [explanation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) of how it works.

I don't know if Facebook is your only concern, but Twitter also has [a similar thing](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started.html).

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't even think about Meta tags. I feel silly now. Anyway, thanks again.